# Why does my question have a ton of views but no votes

Tags: discussion, votes

I am the asker of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213935/why-use-classes-when-programming-a-tkinter-gui-in-python), which has 2600 views and is the top Google result for the query "Why use a class for tkinter" and despite (in my opinion) being a relatively well constructed question, with a well thought out and concise answer, the question and the answer have a total of 4 votes. Is there a rational explanation for this? I'm don't care about the reputation, I just know the purpose of these sites is to share knowledge through a Q/A format, and I believe this is a relatively common question (thus the high views) and usually such questions also have a decent number of votes, thus signifying that the person found the question/answer helpful.

Am I mistaken about this precedent? is there something wrong with my question? Is my question misrepresented by its title?

Comment: 1 upvote is not nothing. 2600 views is not a lot. And since when do votes correlate to views?

Comment: @Oded So you're saying votes *don't* correlate to views? I always thought they did! This is actually interesting. I would love to see a visualization of this.

Comment: @AustinHenley - That many people view a question doesn't mean these people _can_ vote or _will_ vote. Sure, the chances of a someone voting are higher the more people see the question, but it is far from a direct correlation (i.e. have X views get Y votes).

Comment: @Oded I didn't say 1 upvote is nothing, but I have had arguably worse less generally applicable questions with a good deal more. Also, 2600 views may not be breaking any records, but its a respectable amount

Comment: Isn't voting a subjective action of the readers? I look at many questions/responses, upvote the ones I find useful, and ignore the other. Perhaps, you are asking a question that a lot of people are viewing but it is not applicable to most?

Comment: That a question ranks highly on Google search, doesn't imply that it interests the Programmers SE community/members that can answer/vote.

Comment: If I wrote my [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/209364?PostId=213935) right, your question has one positive anon feedback vote also.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is pretty simple, really, people finding your question arrive to the site, don't have an account and can't vote. You should feel good about it, as you've (potentially) helped 2600 or so folks learn something they didn't know before, but you can't expect that to translate into votes.

Look at [the views on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559808/linux-software-watchdog) - it's only got 11 up votes, but it's in the top 5 results for 'linux software watchdog'. That's on SO that has *significantly more* registered users that have the ability to vote.

I pay close attention to making sure I up-vote stuff that I find during the course of doing my job and hobby stuff for just this reason, I know too well how rare the 'thanks' can be as expressed by votes. Still - look at all of the people that now know how that particular kernel module works, that makes me happy.

Views to votes only starts to correlate when something ends up on the front page of HN or Reddit, and even then we're much more likely to see folks that don't have accounts as a significant portion of the viewers. It's .. just how the net works :) When something gets prominent placement in Google's search results, it's a pretty common phenomenon.

We do collect anon feedback from folks, thinking about making that visible to the author of the question / answer only once a post reaches a certain number of views. But, that's .. a different discussion.

Comment: With the 10k pivot table tools gone (yea, they were a bit resource intensive), are there any plans or ways to expose the anon feedback back to users?  (I used that to find questions that were getting lots of negative feedback because of misleading titles)  As it is now, I just poke at things with http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/169976/anon-feedback-explorer

Comment: @MichaelT I'd like to, because otherwise, it's pretty much just wasted and that's a bit of a shame. If you want to write up a feature request that brings back some functionality for what you used it for the most, I'll have a look and see if it's something I can explore in a future (near-future) project.

Comment: There was some discussion about it awhile back in the Whiteboard (see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14935118#14935118 ) though I could look at writing a feature request.  If something has been thought about, I'd rather not distract SE with the ranting and ravings from meta.